# Can stdout and stderr from a child process be correctly interleaved? (Python 2.7, Windows)

Tags: merge, subprocess, stdout, stderr

I've seen several posts on this topic but haven't made much progress.  I would like to run a command line app from a Python script and receive back:
1.) The stdout only
2.) The stderr only
3.) Stdout and stderr together
4.) The exit code from the app
I'm starting to wonder if this is even possible in Python, especially within Windows.  When you have a child process that quickly interleaves stdout and stderr it seems to be really hard to preserve the ordering.

Comment: That isn't an answer to the question though. Merging gives #3 only. How do you get #3 *and* also #1 and #2 at the same time?I don't know the asker's situation, but me, I'm specifically looking at a buildbot which generates 1000 lines of stdout, 1 line of stderr, and 500 more lines of stdout. I want to display the stderr alone, *and* also show it in context, properly interleaved with stdout.